# Where can I download a full PDF of Tanakh?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

I want to read about Judaism, and one of the best sources is to read Torah.
But as I searched, I realized it's not a single book. Rather it's a collection of 24 books and is categorized in pentateuch, histories, wisdom, and prophets.

I searched to download all of these books in one PDF file. But I couldn't find a link.

Do we have them all in one file?

Update: I need English translation, and I thought Torah is 24 books. So I need Tanakh.

Comment: Are you looking for a Hebrew text, an English text, a mix, or some other language?

Comment: Torah = 5 books of Moses, Tanakh = 24 books including Torah. Exactly which one are you looking for?

Comment: You list "pentateuch, histories, wisdom, and prophets". Our traditional division has three parts - the pentateuch; the "prophets" which includes the earlier "histories"; and the "Writings" which is the wisdom books. Chronicles (Divrei Hayamim) is included in the Wisdom writings.

Comment: Suggest you go to mechon-mamre.org, figure out which set of html files you want, and then find someone code-friendly who can stitch them all together for you. Or if you just want the first five books, Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's translation is superb -- you'd have to stitch all the chapters together, but again, that's a light lift for someone who can code: http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp

Comment: @magicker72 I need English translation.

Comment: The alternative could be to go on sefaria select the 'Tanakh' option and there is a download option. You can download it as text and then when open in your microsoft word (or the like) 'save as' / 'print' as a pdf.

Comment: @Dov -- When I do as you say, I get lots of stuff like "</i>;<sup>7</sup><i ".  How do you get a clean formatted text?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi You first select the 'Jewish English Torah' option in the download pull down bar as there are multiple versions available and then in the pull down bar below select the 'without tags' option and it will be clean text.

Comment: @dov. Without tags!  That's the secret. Thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

Although I can't vouch for the Jewish Publication Society translation of the entire Tanach, they have the full English translate available as a downloadable PDF [here](https://jps.org/download-the-tanakh-1917-translation/). I would strongly encourage you to consider taking a few minutes to utilize one of the options in the comments to your question as Sefaria and Rav Aryeh Kaplan are phenomenal resources.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [here](https://chaver.com/Torah-New/English/Text/The%20Structured%20Torah%20(JPS%201917).pdf) if it works for you.

Comment: He's looking for the whole Tanach, not just Chumash, but this looks very cool anyway. Thanks for sharing.